# What is an equivalent of 'unlocked' I/O functions in C99?

Tags: c, io, c99

When I use `--std=c99` GCC defines `__STRICT_ANSI__` and when it is on, the BSD and System V features don't kick in. It implies `__USE_MISC` and `__USE_POSIX` are left undefined.

```
-- stdio.h --
...
#if defined __USE_POSIX || defined __USE_MISC
extern int getc_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
extern int getchar_unlocked (void);
#endif /* Use POSIX or MISC.  */
...
```

In the result, functions that I would like to use are omitted. My question is how can I realize I/O operations on standard streams in C99 but without locking ?

Comment: You can't. But all of this only would make sense if you'd have threads in C99, which don't exist. Since C11 there are threads, potentially, but not yet many implementations. Do you happen to have one?

Comment: As far I know I'm able to create threads in C99. In my case one of created threads is responsible for I/O ops on a single stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99` and it will work the way you want.

Comment: Looks like this short answer is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

POSIX actually says that *all portable programs* should define macro `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` with version of the Posix standard they want the headers to adher to, prior to including any headers. Thus:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
```